# Android Java Two-Way-Binding on Radio Buttons checked

Tags: java, android, two-way-binding

I have a question referring Radio Buttons when using two-way data binding in Android Java. How can I achieve to place the property

```
android:checked="@={patient.gender}"
```

on a Radio Button when there are two Radio Buttons and I need to change the button when the patient is male or female.

I tried:

```
android:checked="@={patient.gender}" //(when patient.gender is false or true)
android:checked="@={patient.gender.equals('m')}" //(when patient.gender would be m or f in a file)
android:checked="@={patient.gender == 'm'}"
android:checked="@={patient.gender ? true : false}"
```

it always gives me a data binding error due to the fact that it's not possible to referr to chars.

How could I manage that problem? :)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

> How could I manage that problem?

Create getter in you pojo class `patient` to check if current patient is male or female

```
public boolean isMale() {
    return gender.equals("m");
}
```

and use this as expression in databinding:

```
android:checked="@{patient.isMale}"
```

Comment: Create setter for `isFemale` inside your patient pojo, because the data binding can not find setter for isFemale field.